# how to perform bulk updation operation in mongodb using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bulkupdate

I am trying to update bulk of documents in `collection` using `mongodb`with different values for field. I have unique `Id` for each `document`. I need to update bulk of records in single update command. How do we update bulk of documents.
Please suggest the approaches to solve this.

Comment: [`bulkWrite()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#bulkWrite). Is there actually a question other than *"Please search the documentation for me"*?

Answer (score 1):

You can update multiple records with below command,

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').update({'condition if any'},{$set: { field:value}}, {multi:true})
```

Comment: It's right . But each documents having changes in different fields not the same field. Not same field for all documents . I need to update whole documents with different values for different fields. Is the mentioned way is feasible way to do so ?